# Drowdownlist populated with Jquery is empty on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, rest, postback

I have a html select dropdown that I populate with data using jquery. I added runat="server" to the select so I can access it programmatically. However when submitting the page, there are no list items in the dropdownlist. Is there a reason for this.

Here is the Jquery call

```
$(window).load(function () {                
         getListDepartments();  // method call to rest service, and it populates correctly

     }
 );
```

aspx

```
// getDepartmentManagers() populates ddlDeparmentManagers with names using jquery
    <select style="display: block;" id="ddlDepartments" class="eight" runat="server" onchange="getDepartmentManagers()">
    </select>

        <select style="display: block;" id="ddlDeparmentManagers" class="eight" runat="server">
        </select>
```

c#

```
protected void lbSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    grdDepartmentEmployees.DataSource = service.FindListBySearch(ddlDepartments.Value, ddlDeparmentManagers.Value);
    grdDepartmentEmployees.DataBind();
}
```

The problem I have is that when I run the c# method above, both dropdownlists seems to be empty.

Comment: Its obvious as ddlDepartments is populated at client side and the changes are not stored anywhere ...like any hidden feild or somewhere. I suggest store the all/selected values/value in hidden field and then access at server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try accessing the values of your drop down lists like this:

```
string department = Page.Request.Form["ddlDepartments"].ToString();
string manager = Page.Request.Form["ddlDeparmentManagers"].ToString();

grdDepartmentEmployees.DataSource = service.FindListBySearch(department, manager);                    
grdDepartmentEmployees.DataBind();
```

Note that retrieving the values this way will give you the `value` of the selected item - depending on how the lists get populated this *may* not be the same as the text that appears in the drop down.

If the value and text are different and you do in fact need the text of the selected item then you will need to do something a bit more complicated:

Add two hidden fields to your page (we will use these to store the selections):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="SelectedDepartmentHiddenField" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="DepartmentManagerHiddenField" runat="server" />
```

In your `getDepartmentManagers` method:

```
$('#SelectedDepartmentHiddenField').val($('#SelectedDepartmentHiddenField').val());
```

Handle the `onchange` event of the `ddlDeparmentManagers` list:

```
<select style="display: block;" id="ddlDeparmentManagers"
    class="eight" runat="server" onchange="departmentManagerChange()">

function departmentManagerChange() {
    $('#DepartmentManagerHiddenField').val($('#ddlDeparmentManagers').val());
}
```

Then in your `lbSearch_Click` method:

```
grdDepartmentEmployees.DataSource =
    service.FindListBySearch(SelectedDepartmentHiddenField.Value,
        DepartmentManagerHiddenField.Value);                    
grdDepartmentEmployees.DataBind();
```

Note that with either approach you won't need the `runat="server"` tags in the drop down lists.

Comment: Thanks. I used the hiddenfield option, as the values and text won't always be the same, and I want to implement one solution.